# Restricting access to programs / tools in a container

Tags: docker

I wanted to ask/start a discussion about what folks here would consider a best practice when it comes to restricting access to things such as `apt-get`, `vi`, `ping`, `wget`, and `curl` within a docker container.

At the moment I have been experimenting with creating AppArmor profiles, to be used as part of the standard run command. For example:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/user1# docker run --rm -it --security-opt apparmor=no-ping debian:jessie bash -i
root@e2028adfa071:/# ping 8.8.8.8
ping: icmp open socket: Permission denied
```

I have also been able to create single profiles for restricting vi and apt-get

vi profile:

```
# Last Modified: Fri Dec  6 11:09:07 2019
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/bin/vim.tiny {
  #include <abstractions/base>

  deny owner /etc/apparmor.d/ r,

  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-*.so mr,
  /usr/bin/vim.tiny mr,

}
```

apt-get profile:

```
# Last Modified: Wed Nov 27 07:59:55 2019
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/bin/apt-get {
  #include <abstractions/base>

  deny capability chown,

  deny /bin/dash x,
  deny /usr/bin/dpkg x,

  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-*.so mr,
  /usr/bin/apt-get mr,

}
```

Ultimately I see this going the route of merging these profiles together so when a container starts up access to `apt-get`, `vi`, `ping`, `wget`, and `curl` are restricted. 
Is there a better/easier way to go about this?

Comment: Remember that, in general, anyone who can run any `docker` command at all can trivially get unrestricted root access to the host.  If you're trying to restrict commands like this, you should severely lock down who's able to access the Docker socket as well; making it mode 0600 owned by `root` is not unreasonable.  (Generally SO questions are much more about actual programming than system administration like this; the [help/on-topic] describes what's on-topic here.)